# Improving the performance of my methods

Tags: java, arrays, performance, hashmap, scalability

Good evening,

I have some pretty bulky and unreadable code which I am trying to simplify, are there any good practices you can recommend

```
public static String getPropertybyId(){
       Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
   System.out.println("Enter an id number to search properties: ");
   int n = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
  reader.close();
  System.out.println(id.get(n) +", "+ property_address.get(n) +", "+ first_name.get(n) +", "+ last_name.get(n) +", "+
  email.get(n) +", "+
  owner_address.get(n) +", "+
  price.get(n)+", "+
  date_sold.get(n));


  return id.get(n) +" ,"+ property_address.get(n) +" ,"+ first_name.get(n) +" ,"+ last_name.get(n) +" ,"+
  email.get(n) +" ,"+
  owner_address.get(n) +" ,"+
  price.get(n);
}


    public static void getTopProperties(){
  price.remove(0);
  int n = 0;
  while (n < price.size()){
    price.set(n,((price.get(n)).substring(1)));
    n = n + 1;
  }

     Collections.sort(price);
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);  // Reading from System.in
 System.out.println("Enter a number for the list size of top properties: ");
 int user = reader.nextInt(); // Scans the next token of the input as an int.
 shrinkTo(price, user);
 reader.close();
 System.out.println(price);

  }

  public static void shrinkTo(List list, int newSize) {
int size = list.size();
if (newSize >= size) return;
for (int i = newSize; i < size; i++) {
    list.remove(list.size() - 1);
}
```

For getPropertybyID I am returning all details for a property such as the owner name and price according to the id number.
Is there a way to hashmap or link the different arrays together so I do not have such a long return statement?

here are my arrays:

```
    private static List<String> id = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> property_address = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> first_name = new ArrayList<String>();
      private static List<String> last_name = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> email = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> owner_address = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> price = new ArrayList<String>();
  private static List<String> date_sold = new ArrayList<String>();
```

for getTopProperties I would like to remove the call to another class and embedded that extra code but I dont know how.

Sorry if my code is not very good im a beginner

Comment: Are you actually interested in performance or readability?

Comment: both, any you can help me with

Comment: Google a jagged array

Comment: Make a class called `Property` with all the required fields, plus getters and setters.  Give it a `toString` method for printing.  And have just one `List<Property>` instead of a whole bunch of `List<String>`s.

Comment: Those are lists, not arrays. Improving working code is the business of codereview.se, but for starters, indent your code consistently.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use OOP. Object Oriented Programming will allow you to simplify this entire genre of problems. Your code will shrink and become more simple/readable.

Read up on it [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/) and be amazed.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the whole thing into a separate method do the String conversion and return it back before returning it back

like so...

```
    private String getPropertyDetials(int index) {
            return id.get(index) +" ,"+ property_address.get(index) +" ,"+ first_name.get(index) +" ,"+ last_name.get(index) +" ,"+
  email.get(index) +" ,"+
  owner_address.get(index) +" ,"+
  price.get(index);
        }
```

Further improving on readability, think of creating a model class and overriding the ToString method to do the above and like FileNotFoundEx you need to look into OOPs concepts

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid duplicating the `String` building exercise, and instead use formatting to build the `String` once. Also, it's a bad idea to `close` the `Scanner` that wraps `System.in` (that's a ***global***). Instead, decouple the reader from the method; and pass that in. Or, even better, separate the concerns and pass in `n`. Like,

```
public static String getPropertybyId(int n) {
    String fmt = "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s";
    String msg = String.format(fmt, id.get(n), property_address.get(n), 
            first_name.get(n), last_name.get(n), email.get(n), 
            owner_address.get(n), price.get(n), date_sold.get(n));
    System.out.println(msg);
    return msg;
}
```